# Bad Access crash while converting to NSMutableattributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

While doing parsing I'm converting HTML string data to attributed string text using below lines of code,

```
 obj.strPlainText=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[obj.strContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]      
                                                          options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                               NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
                                               documentAttributes:nil 
                                                            error:nil];
```

but my app gives bad access
I'm getting an error,

> [NSHTMLWebDelegate retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x7fa9fe027130

Comment: I had also got the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

**But the app will crash if you are running it on ios 8.1,2 or 3.
To avoid the crash what you can do is : run this in a queue. So that it always be on main thread.**

Answer (score 1):

if your are releasing `strPlainText` and also using ARC in your project then no need to write release for `strPlainText`

Comment: i have not written single code of line for release of strPlaintext & my project is ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Using this will solve your problem I think: (if it is 7.0+)

```
NSError* error;
NSMutableAttributedString* str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[source dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                     options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                     NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]}
                                     documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
```

> You have to set **str** to your **obj.strPlainText** like `obj.attributedString = str;`